# How to make multiple logs.txt for network mainframe using batch?

Tags: networking, batch-file, logging

How would I create a batch file that creates multiple logsfiles.txt with the date and time as their names and showing network activity.

Comment: What hardware are you using? What OS? lgofiles.txt created by what? What type of batch file are you talking about? For what type of netork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set datetime=%%i
set log1="c:\onefolder\%datetime%_network.log"
set log2="d:\otherfolder\subfolder\%datetime%_system.log"
ipconfig >%log1%
tasklist >%log2%
```

Comment: how would i then make them put those text files in different folders?

Comment: @Dleader: quite easy. See edited answer

Comment: Thanks You, may i ask you if i have trouble later on with something else?

Comment: just ask a new question. Even I am not always online... ^^